# Transposing columns and using column names as values in another row

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a table like this:

```
BatchNo     | Replication | Bioreactor | Centrifuge | Red | Amber | Green 
------------|-------------|------------|------------|-----|-------|-------
A1-1        | 1           | 1          | 1          | 1   | 0     | 0     
A1-2        | 0           | 0          | 0          | 0   | 0     | 1     
A1-3        | 1           | 0          | 1          | 0   | 1     | 0
```

Steps I need to take:
Make a new column Stage containing the columns- Replication, Bioreactor, Centrifuge etc as categories and transposing their values to populate a column status. Then populate another column RAG based on the occurrence of a value in either Red, Amber or Green fields.

```
BatchNo | Stage       | Status | RAG 
--------|-------------|--------|------
A1-1    | Replication | 1      | Red 
A1-1    | Bioreactor  | 1      | Red 
A1-1    | Centrifuge  | 1      | Red
```

Any ideas how to approach this? Do I need to do 2 tranpositions? Cheers

Comment: RAG is wrong no? shouled be Red, Green, Amber

Comment: Hey no, I am setting the BatchNo as index and for that row A1-1 has a positive flag for Red, so the category would say 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'. I understand the logic is confusing. I am giving a red flag if Replication, Bioreactor and Centrifuge values are all 1, else if all 0, they get green flag, else a mix of 1's and 0's they get amber status.

Comment: got it, thanks for the correction!

Comment: Thanks for the interest Yuca :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case assign the new value for `RAG` , the `melt` the `df`

```
s=df.loc[:,'Red':]
df['RAG']=s.dot(s.columns)
df=df.melt(['BatchNo','RAG'])
df=df.loc[df.value.eq(1)&df.RAG.ne(df.variable)].copy()
df
Out[57]: 
  BatchNo    RAG     variable  value
0    A1-1    Red  Replication      1
2    A1-3  Amber  Replication      1
3    A1-1    Red   Bioreactor      1
6    A1-1    Red   Centrifuge      1
8    A1-3  Amber   Centrifuge      1
```

Comment: btw... you and @cs95/coldspeed change your names too often (-:

Comment: @piRSquared will not change it :-) since other people feel same (hard to recognized me )

Answer (score 2):

#### Set the `index`

```
d = df.set_index('BatchNo')
```

#### `stack` a portion to drop categories into a `MultiIndex`

`loc` is used to filter values equal to `1`

```
cats = np.array(['Replication', 'Bioreactor', 'Centrifuge'])
cat = d[cats].rename_axis('Stage', 1).stack().loc[lambda x: x == 1].to_frame('Status')
```

#### These are assumed to be "One-Hot"

Therefore I can grab the first ones with `idxmax`

```
rag = d[np.array(['Red', 'Amber', 'Green'])].idxmax(1).rename('RAG')
```

#### After renaming axes and columns appropriately...

I should be able to `join`

```
cat.join(rag).reset_index()

  BatchNo        Stage  Status    RAG
0    A1-1  Replication       1    Red
1    A1-1   Bioreactor       1    Red
2    A1-1   Centrifuge       1    Red
3    A1-3  Replication       1  Amber
4    A1-3   Centrifuge       1  Amber
```

Comment: Hey this is perfect, what if I want to include not just the entries with status of 1, I wanted to select values that have both 1 and 0 for Status?

Comment: Oh wait I just remove the .loc[lambda x] selection and got exactly what I want. You deserve a green tick. Thank you for your efforts :)